# osmdroid marker info window dont show after clustering markers

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid to display open street map in an android app
the problem is when clustering markers when click on marker, info window of markers do not shows.
this is how i add markers for clustering:

```
    RadiusMarkerClusterer poiMarkers = new RadiusMarkerClusterer(this);
    Drawable clusterIconD = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_cluster);
    Bitmap clusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) clusterIconD).getBitmap();
    poiMarkers.setIcon(clusterIcon);
    poiMarkers.getTextPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    poiMarkers.getTextPaint().setTextSize(12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density); //taking into account the screen density
    poiMarkers.mAnchorU = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER;
    poiMarkers.mAnchorV = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER;
    poiMarkers.mTextAnchorV = 0.40f;
    map.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);

    for (int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++) {
        final Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
        startMarker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(places.get(i).getLat(), places.get(i).getLng()));

        startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_new_loc));

        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
        MyInfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.map_marker_info_window, map);
        infoWindow.setPlace(places.get(i));
        startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);
        poiMarkers.add(startMarker);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadiusMarkerClusterer` is not supposed to show info windows for clusters. A cluster represents a group of individual markers and so it's impossible to decide, which info window should be displayed.

You can check [source code of the RadiusMarkerClusterer](https://github.com/grote/OSMBonusPack/blob/master/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/RadiusMarkerClusterer.java) class.

Markers (which represents clusters) are instantiated in the method `buildClusterMarker`:

```
@Override public Marker buildClusterMarker(StaticCluster cluster, MapView mapView) {
    Marker m = new Marker(mapView);
    m.setPosition(cluster.getPosition());
    m.setInfoWindow(null); //<===== there you can see, no info window
    m.setAnchor(mAnchorU, mAnchorV);

    Bitmap finalIcon = Bitmap.createBitmap(mClusterIcon.getWidth(), mClusterIcon.getHeight(), mClusterIcon.getConfig());
    Canvas iconCanvas = new Canvas(finalIcon);
    iconCanvas.drawBitmap(mClusterIcon, 0, 0, null);
    String text = "" + cluster.getSize();
    int textHeight = (int) (mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent());
    iconCanvas.drawText(text,
            mTextAnchorU * finalIcon.getWidth(),
            mTextAnchorV * finalIcon.getHeight() - textHeight / 2,
            mTextPaint);
    m.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(mapView.getContext().getResources(), finalIcon));

    return m;
}
```

If you want to have info windows for your clusters, you can create custom `MarkerClusterer` class, by inheriting from `RadiusMarkerClusterer` and overriding this method. Just call parent version and inject your desired info window into the `Marker` instance.

Comment: i don't want to display info window for clusters , i have set info window for every markers inside cluster the problem is when i click on a marker info window of marker don't show

Comment: @edalat-feizi I see, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @EdalatFeizi Well in this case I am afraid I am not able to spot the proble. I checked the source of the library and it seems it should work and your code is correct. You may try to add OnMarkerClickListener to all markers and call marker.showInfoWindow() from it, but thats exactly what default implementation in Marker does.

Comment: thanks for your response,i also add a click listener to every marker before add to cluster but on click of markers never called.

Comment: @EdalatFeizi Yes, that's what I expected. The thing is, the part of your code you included in the question is correct. I double-checked example from the library ( https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPackTuto/src/main/java/com/example/osmbonuspacktuto/MainActivity.java ), copied your code into the example and did necessary modifications to get it running and it works.

Comment: @EdalatFeizi Problem must be in some other part of your code. Are you sure, that clicking/tapping works without clustering? Are there any other overlays, that might interfere? Isn't there any problem in the MyInfoWindow class?

Comment: @EdalatFeizi I just checked implementation in OSMNavigator (updateUIWithPOI), it works fine. Your issue is in the code you didn't provide.